# How to center multiple div elements within a parent div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center smaller divs within a larger div. My code looks like this:

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBJbAP)

```css
    div.box-collective {
     background-color: grey;
     width: 100%;
    }
    
    div.box {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     border: 1px solid black;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <h1>My boxes</h1>
    
     <div class="box-collective">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Since its impossible to explain what I am trying to do with words, please look at these pics to get a better idea:

[image]

In the above case, the screen width is large (desktop). Basically, my code looks like the top version. I result I want is the one on the bottom, that is, the group of boxes centered perfectly.

[image]

In this case, the screen is small, and since each box is inline-block, they automatically go to a new line when the screen is resized. However, once again I want to center them, similar to the right pic.

How can I achieve this using pure CSS? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just add `text-align:center;` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBJboR

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply put `text-align:center;` on your `div.box-collective` class.

```css
div.box-collective {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}

div.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>My boxes</h1>

    <div class="box-collective">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow it was that simple huh? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yup! Just a heads up the content inside each `.box` will be aligned `center` too. If you want that to be left adjacent, you'd have to do `div.box-collective>.box{text-align:left}`

Answer (score 3):

## Solution 1 (modern browsers) - using flexbox

I think this is a must have in the toolkit for all modern web-devs.

- [Awesome tutorial / cheatsheet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.container.small {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
.container .box{
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container small">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

## Solution 2 - `display: inline-block` & `text-align: center;`:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: grey;
}

.container.small {
 width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
.container .box{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container small">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You get some love from me too. Just for reference: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

`text-align: center;` works in this case, but for a little more control (and without having to reset text alignment) use flexbox

```
div.box-collective {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```